# No me pasa la condición, no me valida

Tags: c#, visual-studio, condiciones, checkbox, gridview

estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tengo un griview y dentro de un Itemtemplate tengo un checkbox, tengo una condición donde me valida si alguno esta checkeado, principalmente quiero que me capture un dato de una celda y me lo muestre en el label; lo revise paso por paso pero no me pasa de la condición,es decir, se queda en el if, les agradecería si pudiesen ayudarme.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvProfe" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chbItem" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdProfesor" HeaderText="IdProfesor" />

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<p class="auto-style3">
  &nbsp;
  <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p class="auto-style3">
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContar" runat="server" OnClick="lnkMostrar_Click">Contar</asp:LinkButton>
```

```css
protected void lnkMostrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CheckBox chbId;
  int contador=0;
  string val=string.Empty;
  foreach (GridViewRow grvRow in gvProfe.Rows) {
    chbId=(CheckBox)grvRow.FindControl("chbItem");
    if (chbId.Checked) {
     
      val=grvRow.Cells[2].Text;
      contador++;
    }
    else {
      lblMensaje.Text="xd "+contador;
    }
  }
}
```

si pudiesen ayudarme, ahí muestro el código del gridview y del proceso

Answer (score 1):

A ver, lo que veo es que tú código cuenta en la variable contador indicando qué CheckBox está marcado, y cuando no lo está pone el valor de dicha variable en un label.
El siguiente código recorre el GridView y va contando los CheckBox que están marcados y al final nos muestra en lblMensaje la cantidad de los que están marcados:

```
protected void lnkMostrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   CheckBox chbId;
   int contador=0;
   string val=string.Empty;
   foreach (GridViewRow grvRow in gvProfe.Rows) 
   {
      chbId=(grvRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chbItem") as CheckBox);
      if (chbId.Checked) 
      {
          val=grvRow.Cells[2].Text; // Esto no sé para qué sirve
                                    // ya que sólo usas val para
                                    // asignarle el valor.
          contador++;
      }
   }
   // Muestra los CheckBox encontrados que están marcados.
   lblMensaje.Text="xd " + contador.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Si, disculpa, en la línea que no sabes para que es, lo que principalmente intento es obtener un Dato, pues puse el Label para ver si me capturaba el dato, es decir que en esa línea estoy capturando la celda 2 que sería específicamente el dato que quiero capturar

Comment: Resuelve tu pregunta? Arroja algún error?

Comment: Voy a intentar, en 2 min te respondo, de  verdad muchas gracias por quererme ayudar

Comment: Si, me arroja un error que dice "El operar '+' no se puede aplicar a operando de tipo 'String' y 'grupo de métodos '

Comment: En el código que te muestro la variable contador es convertida a String para poder concatenar con el operador + y formar el texto que contendrá el label.

Comment: Oye muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya pude solucionarlo, te agradezco demasiado